# backbone.js - parentheses needed after "new" keyword?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I've been working through codeschool.com's tutorial on backbone.js
And submitted:

```
var AppRouter = new Backbone.Router.extend({
  //code
});
$(function(){ AppRouter.start() });
```

and it gave the following error message:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'AppRouter.start()') :28 :14
```

but adding a single parentheses solved the problem

```
var AppRouter = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  //code
}));
```

I feel like it should have still worked before... What was happening when there was one less parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was using `Backbone.Router.extend` as the constructor (with the parentheses going as arguments to the constructor, not the result of the `Backbone.Router.extend` call (where the call to `Backbone.Router.extend` returns a function to be used as a constructor).  For example, compare:

```
function Test()
{   return function () { this.a = 2; };
}

console.log(new Test()); // function () { this.a = 2; }
console.log(new (Test())); // { a: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered another way, you need to be working with an instance of Backbone.Router, which you can first extend with your own router. Such as:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        // code
    }
});

var router = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

The code in your example is evaluating the extend call first, then creating an instance with the return value. The end result is the same, but could be a bit misleading if you don't know the parentheses are causing the evaluation to take place.